# How to backup app programmatically on android

Tags: java, android, backup

How to backup app programmatically on android?

Comment: What do you want to backup ?  Your application data ?

Answer (score 3):

As of Android 2.2 (Froyo), Google has made available a cloud based backup service for apps.
Check it out at the link below for more info about it from Google.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html

If you wan't something for pre-Froyo devices, you'll need to implement your own backup service.

Comment: I talk about app backuping(we get apk file for install in the future,with data in it) how it realesed in Astro or Estrongs file explorer